# buscar a quantidade de caracter de uma imput

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-eventos

1) Crie um campo  e aplique os seguintes controles com base nos eventos abaixo:

• No evento de foco modifique o background do input para amarelo.

•Quando o campo perder o foco, recupere o seu respectivo valor e: 
o Caso o conteúdo contido no campo tenha menos de 3 caracteres o mesmo deve ter seu background alterado para vermelho.
o Caso o conteúdo contido no campo tenha 3 caracteres ou mais o background deve ser alterado para verde.

estou com difulculdade para entender fazer a segunda parte.

Como fazer a contagem dos caracter?

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Answer (score 2):

Vamos supor que seu campo seja este

```
<input type="text" id="container" name="fname"><br>
```

o javascript fornece um atribuidor de evento chamado onfocus e onblur , o onfocus funciona quando você foca com o mouse sobre o elemento e o onblur quando você tira o foco fora

vamos para um exemplo resolvendo seu problema :

Primeiro recupere sua div pelo id

```
var inputName = document.getElementById("container");
```

Agora vamos colocar o evento onfocus e colocar a cor amarela no foco

```
inputName.onfocus = function(){
 InputName.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

Agora vamos registrar o onblur e validar a quantidade de caracteres

```
inputName.onblur = function(){
 Name = InputName.value;
 if(Name.length >= 3){
   InputName.style.backgroundColor = "green";
 }
 else{
   InputName.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
}
```

A função length conta a quantidade de caracteres em uma String , então eu faço as validações de acordo com seu exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado , estou respondendo a minha primeira pergunta , então posso ter explicado de um jeito não muito fácil , aceitou dicas de como melhorar as minhas explicações .

Comment: Obrgiado @FelipheStival otima explicação.